# Finder closes after emptying trash or ejecting a disk

Tags: macos, finder, trash

Is it possible to change some Finder settings so that it doesn't automatically close the window when the Trash is emptied or a usb disk/hard drive is ejected?

Comment: Sorry, no. The Finder is not designed that way.

Comment: This is just what the Finder does. If you have a Finder window open on a resource that goes away (disk, network drive, etc), then the window closes. I find it a bit annoying too. If you want the Finder window to stay open, then you need to select a different disk before ejecting, unmounting, deleting the one the window is open to.

Comment: Press ⌘⇧H before you eject the disk or empty the trash, and the Finder window won't close. It only closes when you are viewing the trash or disk that you empty/eject.  If you otherwise change the active directory shown in the Finder window, it won't close.

Comment: Do you want the window to stay on the trash page or go to another page?

Answer (score -1):

You could probably write a script with grep and diskutility that opens finder whenever the count of disks changes?